# two player game theory question

Tags: combinatorics

I am wondering how to solve the following question:

A and B play a game using 50 cards numbered 1 through
50. They alternate with A going first. On each turn a player chooses a card from the deck and adds it to one of two piles. After all 50 cards are in the two piles, the total sum of the cards in each pile is calculated, and B wins the difference of the sums of the two piles. B wants to win as much as possible, and A wants B to win as little as possible. If they both play with perfect strategy, find the amount that B wins.

I tried some strategies for this problem and I think that 50 is the least amount to win but I am confused on how to prove this. I think that just taking one less than the other player should suffice to keep a constant sum.

Comment: Who gets to see the values of the cards played? Does $\ A\ $ get  players get to see the values of the cards played by $\ B\ $, and $\ B\ $ the value of the cards played by $\ A\ $, for instance, or does each of them only get to see the values of the cards played by him or herself?

Comment: Each person sees everything the other person does.

Comment: anybody? I will post my proof below.

Answer (score 1):

B can guarantee a win if he takes the highest valued card available and places it in the highest valued stack.  The best counter that A has is to place the next highest card available into the lower valued stack.  The difference increases by at least one after each round.

If B takes less than the highest card available, A can even the stacks.

Since B can always leverage a differential, A must do what he can to keep the two piles as equal as possible.  His opening move is to take the 1.

A takes the 1 and starts the first stack.  B takes the 50 and places it in the same stack.  A places the 49 in the second stack.  etc.  At the end of the game pile 1 has 26 cards totaling 651 and pile 2 has 24 cards totaling 624.  A win of 27.

Comment: I think you might have been confused about the rules; $A$ wants to minimize the difference, $B$ wants to maximize. Your strategy for both players has them doing the opposite.

Comment: You are right, I had the roles reversed.  Doesn't change the basic strategy, though.